# NaN: Aynchronous parallel computing

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, hashmap

I am doing a parallel computing using multhi-threading in java. May data structure is HashMap. My algorithm does not have any division operation and square root to. it is stochastic gradient descent.Even then i am getting `NaN`.I would like to know if there is multiple access , read write in hashmap, does it cause any undefined problem? If yes,
how would i get rid of it?

[EDIT]

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Double>>entry: Matrix.entrySet()){
        sum = sum + Math.exp(getScore(contextFeatureVector,entry.getValue()));
    }
```

`getScore` method computes inner product. The returned value is `infinity`.

[EDIT 2]

In this above method, `Matrix` is :

```
  Map<Integer,ArrayList<Double>> Matrix = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Double>>();
```

I am still getting the `NaN` .Is it due to due to the way i am accessing value. Can somebody please answer with clear intuition?

Comment: Yes, a HashMap isn't threadsafe, so that could cause trouble. Can you post some code that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2):

you should be using java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap if you going to have two threads adding and removing entries from there.  you be be NaN when one of your thread removes a key that the other thread just got a handel on it and will call value for key.

Or you could block on the HashMap Object when adding/remove entries.

[edit]
 Couple of thoughts:

• Integers are probablly not very reliable to sync on. (unless your
   doing the extra work of making sure you don't have two Integer for
   the same value, so you must keep track and reuse Integer.)

• NaN means your most likely getting a nil for a number. 
• division by 0 
• calculating sqrt of a negative number.

### • NaN != Infinity

Can you log values To console as you use them or just find the line where your having the exption thrown from. Maybe just dump out the whole map.

This map you have now is the way to go but you need to ensure its gettin what it needs to do its thing.